# knife advice - good knife and good care

Tags: knives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I care for my knives?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/315/how-should-i-care-for-my-knives)

At home i have this knife:
http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/product.asp?SKU=11097073&RN=1038&

I picked that one up several years ago, but haven't done much in the way of any maintenance on it. I did pick up a cheap sharpener but it didn't seem to have much effect so i stopped using it.

The knife seems dull to me. It doesn't cut through things as easily as i think it should. For example, resting the blade on a ripe firm tomatoe, i would think the blade should be able to slice through without me applying much, or any, downward pressure and without pushing in the shape of the tomatoe. It should basically just start slicing through under it's own weight and without squishing the tomatoe at all.

Let me know if that sounds like an unrealistic expectation.

So i have 2 questions:

1. is that (or was it before i didn't maintain it correctly) a good knife? In searching here i saw victorinox suggested as a good value. Is the one i have worth keeping or should i purchase a new one?
2. Does anyone know of a chain store (or local store in the LA area) that i can take it to to get it re-sharpened? And what should i be doing to maintain it's usefulness after it's re-sharpened?

I assume the answer to the 2nd part of question 2 is this: [How should I care for my knives?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/315/how-do-you-care-for-your-knives) - specifically the part about getting honing steel? does it matter which one i get or can i just get a $10-$15 one on amazon?

Thanks

Comment: This question is primarily asking for shopping advice, which isn't something we provide. However, because there are good answers, I'm going to merge this with [How should I care for my knives?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/315)