# Do I need to wipe/clean my knife after sharpening/honing?

Tags: sharpening, knife-safety

I'm <strike>sharpening</strike> honing my cutting knives with a (honing) steel. I'm sure I read/saw somewhere that you should wipe your knives after <strike>sharpening</strike> honing to remove any shards of metal. Is this correct or necessary? Am I getting confused with something else? It doesn't seem plausible to me that this would create metal shards, but obviously it being a safety issue I wanted to check. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I care for my knives?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/315/how-should-i-care-for-my-knives)

Comment: if you allow more time before marking the correct answer you may get more answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the type of honing rod and the technique you use for honing, you will remove more or less metal from the blade. You can confirm whether your rod removes metal by wiping the blade on a white tea cloth after honing. If you see a grey residue on the cloth then metal has been removed and you can decide yourself whether you want that in your food.

**Types of Honing Rod**

- **Steel rods,** of the type that are perfectly smooth will not remove noticeable amounts of steel from a blade. Polished honing rods are used for straightening a curled blade edge. Other types have shallow grooves cut down the length of the rod that bite into the blade and shave off metal particles.
- **Ceramic rods** are slightly abrasive and will remove small amounts of metal.
- **Diamond coated rods** are used for sharpening in place of a whetstone and will remove relatively large amounts of metal.

What technique you use for honing depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you only need to realign the edge of a well maintained knife, then two or three swipes on both sides of the blade, maintaining light pressure should be sufficient.

If you do this with a polished steel, then I would be surprised if you need to wipe the blade afterwards. If you use one of the other types of rod, then you are also removing metal from your knife and you may want to strop the knife and give it a quick wipe after.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier although it doesn't coincide exactly with what I have said, [this link](http://www.canadacutlery.com/product/facts_on_steels.pdf) is the source of some of this information. The rest is an amalgam of information from my own experience and multiple (largely forgotten) online sources.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I tried to re-track some of my sources and came across [this](http://youtu.be/5iZE42iGreE) on YouTube which agrees with my advice to strop the knife after using a diamond coated rod. And [this](http://youtu.be/L1VXqDlIY7k) video, also from expert village also suggests using a strop after using a ceramic rod. There are quite a few knife sharpening videos from expert village that are worth a look.

Comment: Finally, [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1l8I--McvQ&feature=share&list=PLD43B7CCE6C54C809) confirms what I say regarding technique.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Yes, you should clean after sharpening, which is not the same as honing.</strike>

No, after honing, it's not necessary.

By sharpening, you take some metal off the edge of the knife to create an edge.

By honing, you realign the edge of the knife.

See [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/321/641) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out I was using the wrong terminology. I was talking about honing with a honing steel, not sharpening. So honing does not require cleaning afterward?

Comment: I never clean after honing, and I've never seen anybody else do it (butcher, fish-monger, cooks, etc.)

Comment: Honing does remove VERY small broken shards of metal. If the knife is clean and non-magnetic (it should) these will fall to the bench or floor during the honing process

Comment: @TFD, do you have any sources for that?

Comment: @Andrew0-Ferrier Physics, my kitchen bench, white cotton cloth or a magnet. The particles are VERY small, but since the hone is harder than the blade, this will always happen

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of a few seconds running the knife under the tap, or wiping it with a damp cloth, why would you not do this? Regardless of whether you remove large pieces of metal or just tiny particles - is it worth the risk of getting any of this in the food you prepare? I always give my knives a rinse and then dry them with a clean cloth.

Answer (score 2):

I use the back side of a leather belt, or a leather strop, to finish the edge of my knives after sharpening and/or honing. This removes any tiny particles of metal from the knife (or razor) as well as polishes it. I wash and dry the implement after this step before use. I learned this technique from a barber.